# a hard close look

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, word-usage

Are "close" and "hard" the same below?

> He took a ***close*** look at the cat.
>   He took a ***hard*** look at the cat.

Or are they subtly different?  For this particular usage, web dictionaries appear to define "close" with "hard" and "hard" with "close".

Comment: This is a question of writing style, so it's off topic here but on topic at SE.writers. The answer to your question, however, is that writers sometimes use synonyms in this way to intensify their expression: it's far better than saying "a **very** {hard / close [CHOOSE ONE]} look". It also gives the sentence a different sound & feeling. Careful writers are sensitive to such things. I'm neither endorsing nor condemning the usage, but I see nothing unusual or inherently wrong with it.

Comment: Not at all the same. **hard**: _cool or uncompromising_  
"we took a long hard look at our profit factor" - **close** - _examining in more detail_

Comment: @BillFranke So, it would make no difference in this as well:  "He took a ***close/hard*** look at the evidence."

Comment: @mplungjan: I don't see how it's possible to take a "hard" look without taking a "close" look. OTOH, I can see how it's possible to do it the other way around. Ergo, I conclude that there is a small overlap, as does [Thesaurus.com (_compact_, p3 & _factual_, p4)](http://thesaurus.com/browse/hard?page=3&qsrc=121).

Comment: The long hard look includes the close.

Comment: Yes, it all depends on context. Dictionaries & thesauruses are fine tools that I use every day, but writers & speakers don't always follow the dictates of those tomes. They use words in context, not necessarily based on dictionary definitions. You can take a close look at a _Playboy_ bunny picture because it's attractive from afar, but you'd take a hard look at it once you noticed evidence of airbrushing. Different context, different meanings.

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes, it does, which is why there is a small degree of synonymity between the words: "close" is superfluous if "hard" is used.

Comment: So they are not the same.

Comment: @BillFranke So, "close" and "hard" are vaguely the same after all.

Comment: @Nortonn S: In some contexts, yes. You're pretty good at coming up with many examples of such thinly synonymous words.

Comment: @masner: As mplungjan said: "The long hard look includes the close." Sometimes & in some contexts they are synonymous; they're rarely interchangeable. I've already given an example of a "soft close look", & mplungjan confirms that all "hard looks" are "hard close looks", which is why "close" is superfluous: it's redundant in "hard close look". They're not "vaguely the same" but only sometimes synonymous: there's a difference.

Comment: Those who thought this is NARQ may have read the comments and answers now.

Answer (score 1):

They do not mean the same thing. The distinction is more than subtle.

> [macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/look_46)
>   **have a good/close look (=look carefully):** *He got out of the car so he could have a closer look.*
>
> **take a (long) hard look at something (=think very carefully and seriously about it):** *You seem to be permanently stressed out – I think you should take a long hard look at your life.*

Furthermore, while some dictionaries do show the two phrases as nearly interchangeable,
*close look* is synonymous with *scrutiny*: careful examination;
*hard look* implies dispassionate, cool or uncompromising.

Answer (score -1):

It's one of those phrases to emphasise the fact that someone's had a good look at the cat
"Close'(rhyming with dose) in this sense is used to mean 'close up' to the cat. "hard' means you looked at it for a long time, trying to see every detail.

Comment: I would think that the cat had done something to deserve a hard look

Comment: So, it would make no difference in this as well:  "He took a ***close/hard*** look at the evidence."

Comment: @masener: No, it would make no difference. When looking at evidence, one carefully examines every detail: close and hard.

Answer (score -1):

*Close* means with attention to detail.

*Hard* means without leniency, or emotional softness.

The two overlap, but aren't exactly the same.